# How to loop through Array of Objects to find ID then return a sibling key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have a complex Array of Objects below, and I have a `term_id` to search on. I'm trying to find the matching `term_id`, then return the associated `ticker: name` from the same Object from which I found the `term_id`.

```
container = [Object, Object];

// container:
[
    0: Object {
        tags: [
            0: {
                term: "tag_name_1",
                term_id: 1111
            },
            0: {
                term: "tag_name_2",
                term_id: 2222
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker1"
        }
    },
    1: Object {
        tags: [
            0: {
                term: "tag_name_3",
                term_id: 3333
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker2"
        }
    }
]
```

How would you accomplish this? Is there an easy way with [_lodash](https://lodash.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// You can do this with native JS:

var container = [{tags: [{term: "tag_name_1",term_id: 1111},{term: "tag_name_2",term_id: 2222}],ticker: {name: "ticker1"}},{tags: [{term: "tag_name_3",term_id: 3333}],ticker: {name: "ticker2"}}];

function search (container, id) {
  var contains = false;
  var result;

  container.forEach(function(obj){
    obj.tags.forEach(function(innerData){
      if (innerData.term_id === id) {
        contains = true;
      }
    })
    if (contains) {
      result = obj.ticker.name;
      contains = false;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(search(container, 1111));
```

Comment: Shouldn't your search function do something with the result? Like return it?

Comment: Thanks yeah the `forEach` works :) I need to Gist this, 4 mins

Comment: I had the return in the forEach which wasn't working.  Fixed that and made it run as a code snippet.  Check your console and hit run.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this. For example:

```
function find(arr, t) {
    var ticker = null;

    arr.some(function (doc) {
        var tagMatch = doc.tags.some(function (tag) {
            return tag.term_id === t;
        });

        if (tagMatch) {
            ticker = doc.ticker.name;
        }

        return tagMatch;
    });

    return ticker;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakeclarkson/j277gk8r/).

Comment: Very nice and clean :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you. It's a function that you can pass your objects into and a *term_id* you search for and it returns found ticker names:

```
var objs = [
    {
        tags: [
            {
                term: "tag_name_1",
                term_id: 1111
            },
            {
                term: "tag_name_2",
                term_id: 2222
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker1"
        }
    },
    {
        tags: [
            {
                term: "tag_name_3",
                term_id: 3333
            }
        ],
        ticker: {
            name: "ticker2"
        }
    }
];

function getTickerNamesById(objs,id){
  var foundNames = [];
  objs.forEach(function(obj){
    obj.tags.forEach(function(term){
      if(term.term_id===id)foundNames.push(obj.ticker.name);
    });
  });
  return foundNames;
}

getTickerNamesById(objs,3333); // ["ticker2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

A forEach() loop works, though there is no way to prevent it from cycling through the entire object once the id is matched.  Assuming the id's are unique, a option with better performance would be the while loop:

```
function findId(id,container) {
  var i = 0,
      j;

  while (i < container.length) {
    j = 0;
    while (j < container[i].tags.length) {
      if (container[i].tags[j].term_id === id) {
       return container[i].ticker.name;
      }
      j += 1;
    }
    i += 1;
  }
  throw "item not found";
}
```

If your containers will be large you may want to consider this optimization.  If you preferred a functional approach, you could accomplish a similar thing with [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), both of which exit out given a specified condition.